# className not populated in Gatsby with Bulma

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, bulma

I am trying to set the className of a div using:

```
  render() {

    const textStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "200px",
      left: "200px"
    }

    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className={textStyle}> My text is Test</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

However when I inspect all I get is

`<div class="[object Object]"> My text is Test</div>`

I'm not sure why this is not working.

I can use Bulma modifiers OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

className receives a string, not an object

if you want to use your textStyle object use this:

```
<div style={textStyle}> My text is Test</div>
```

more about className: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html